# SpringBoot - I tried to pass parameters from a view to controller, and I tried to display result in another view, but it doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, model-view-controller

I tried to build a form in home.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadfile" th:action="@{/uploadfile}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"  accept=".xls"/> <br/><br/>
<label for="fname">order address:</label> 
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="50">
<label for="lname">order account:</label> 
<input type="text" id="account" name="account" size="50"><br/><br/>
<label for="lname">:</label> 
<button type="submit">summit/button>
</form>
```

result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>result</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${message}">
 <h2 th:text="${message}"/></div>

<form action="/download" method="post">
    <text name="filename" type="text" value="${downloadfile}"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="download XML" />
</form>

 

</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller

```
  @PostMapping("/uploadfile")
  public  ModelAndView uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(name="address", required = false) String myaddress,
            @RequestParam(name="account", required = false) String myaccount
               ) 
          {
          ....................
          ..................
          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("result"); //tried to return this parameters
           model.addObject("excecontentslist",tempExcelcontentList); //tried to show the contents of Excel
           model.addObject("message",consequencemsg);//tried to show the message we have
           model.addObject("downloadfile",xmlfilename); //tried to show the xml which is gonna download
           return model;//got 404 error when all things has been done
      }
```

all I trying to do was to send datas which is model to result.jsp to show the data out there,but it doesn't work,just showed the 404 error  ,any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue please ? Have you try debugging your code ? Are variables well provided ?

Comment: @BenjaminD thank you for answering my question, I have tried debugging my code,my variables are well provided,but unfortunately it occured  ' the Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).' unexpectedly, but in console section of Eclipse ,it didn't show any exception,that's bizarre ,it was supposed to go to the result.jsp when it executed the " return model;"

Comment: `result` doesn't map to `Result.jps` (names are case sensitive. Also I would strongly suggest something like Thymeleaf or Mustache instead of JSP due to limitations with JSP and embedded containers.

Comment: @M.Deinum,Ok cool ,thank you

Comment: How is your view resolver configured and where are your JSP files located.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't have any configuration which where the JSP files located,but the SpringBoot done this for me automatically,I just putten all my JSP files into a /src/main/webapp folder though

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't do that for you if you haven't configured it. You are probably directly accessing `home.jsp` in your URL instead of `/home`. If you haven't configured the view resolver return `result.jsp` from your controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much for telling me this,I gonna Google how to configurate it,this might be the answer for my question.thank you

Comment: Add `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` and `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/` to your configuration. Although it is recommended to place your jsp files in a non-accessible location like `/WEB-INF/views` then change `spring.mvc.view.prefix` to `/WEB-INF/views/`. And you will need to add something for the `home.jsp` as well (a mapping to the view name).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much